# Tensorflow 2.0 : frozen graph support

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Will the support for frozen graph continue in tensorflow 2.0 or deprecated?
I mean the scripts and APIs to create/optimize frozen graph from saved_model. Also the APIs to run the inference for the same.

Assuming it will be supported in future, what is the recommended method to run the inference on frozen graph in tensorflow 2.0 ?

Comment: what do you mean by frozen graph?

Comment: Most of the time, tensorflow 1.x models are shared by freezing the graph for inference. You can refer this for more details on : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The freeze graph APIs - [`freeze_graph.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) and [`converter_variables_to_constants`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/convert_variables_to_constants) - will not be supported in TensorFlow 2.0.

In 2.0, the primary export format is [SavedModels](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/saved_model) so APIs are built to directly support SavedModels.
 Inference on existing frozen graphs can be run using the `v1.compat` path.

Answer (score 2):

Now, `freeze_graph` is officially gone with TensorFlow 2.0 stable release.

[Check Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you use estimator to biuld a model, you can using tf.estimator.Estimator.export_saved_model to freeze your model.

```
model = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn, 
    model_dir=model_saved_dir)

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    # in here, my input is 512 x 512 single channel image
    feature = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 512, 512, 1], name="inputs")
    return tf.estimator.export.TensorServingInputReceiver(feature, feature)

model.export_saved_model(model_saved_dir, serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

this code is work in tensorflow 2.0

or you use keras, You can refer to the steps of the official website
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format