# How to save Keras model as frozen graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am working with Tensorflow 2.0 and want to store the following Keras model as frozen graph.

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=[100]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.save('./models/')
```

I can't find any good examples how to do this in Tensorflow 2.0. I have found the [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) file in the Tensorflow Github repository but find it hard to wrap my head around it.

I load the file mentioned above using:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph import freeze_graph
```

But what exactly do I have to provide to the `freeze_graph` function itself? Here I marked the arguments where I am not sure with a questionmark.

```
freeze_graph(input_graph=?,
             input_saver='',
             input_binary=False,
             input_checkpoint=?,
             output_node_names=?,
             restore_op_name='',
             filename_tensor_name='',
             output_graph='./frozen_graph.pb',
             clear_devices=True,
             initializer_nodes='')
```

Can someone provide a simple example that shows how I can store the model above as a frozen graph using the `freeeze_graph` function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Freeze_Graph is now gone in Tensorflow 2.0.
 You can check it here [Tensorflow 2.0 : frozen graph support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562078/tensorflow-2-0-frozen-graph-support).

Except for the ***.save*** method that you have in your code.
 
***.save*** Method is already saving a .pb ready for inference.
As an alternative, you can also use the below code.

You can also use ***convert_variables_to_constants_v2***

Below is the sample code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()

# Convert Keras model to ConcreteFunction
full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype, name="yourInputName"))
# Get frozen ConcreteFunction
frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()
layers = [op.name for op in frozen_func.graph.get_operations()]
print("-" * 50)
print("Frozen model layers: ")
for layer in layers:
    print(layer)
print("-" * 50)
print("Frozen model inputs: ")
print(frozen_func.inputs)
print("Frozen model outputs: ")
print(frozen_func.outputs)
# Save frozen graph from frozen ConcreteFunction to hard drive
tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir="./frozen_models",
                  name="frozen_graph.pb",
                  as_text=False)

### USAGE ##
def wrap_frozen_graph(graph_def, inputs, outputs, print_graph=False):
    def _imports_graph_def():
        tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")

    wrapped_import = tf.compat.v1.wrap_function(_imports_graph_def, [])
    import_graph = wrapped_import.graph

    print("-" * 50)
    print("Frozen model layers: ")
    layers = [op.name for op in import_graph.get_operations()]
    if print_graph == True:
        for layer in layers:
            print(layer)
    print("-" * 50)

    return wrapped_import.prune(
        tf.nest.map_structure(import_graph.as_graph_element, inputs),
        tf.nest.map_structure(import_graph.as_graph_element, outputs))

## Example Usage ###
# Load frozen graph using TensorFlow 1.x functions
with tf.io.gfile.GFile("./frozen_models/frozen_graph.pb", "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    loaded = graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

# Wrap frozen graph to ConcreteFunctions
frozen_func = wrap_frozen_graph(graph_def=graph_def,
                                inputs=["yourInputName:0"],
                                outputs=["Identity:0"],
                                print_graph=True)
print("-" * 50)
print("Frozen model inputs: ")
print(frozen_func.inputs)
print("Frozen model outputs: ")
print(frozen_func.outputs)
# Get predictions for test images
predictions = frozen_func(yourInputName=tf.constant([[3.]]))
# Print the prediction for the first image
print("-" * 50)
print("Example prediction reference:")
print(predictions[0].numpy())
```

Comment: Can I assign custom input and output node names such as `input` and `output` instead of `x` and `Identity`? Is the nesting of the `_imports_graph_def()` functino inside the `wrap_frozen_graph()` function really necessary?

Comment: @random9 Yes, it could be change and the _import_graph_def() is also important.

Comment: Can you please show how the variable names can be changed?

Comment: Hi @random9,For the input, just add a name on this line tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype, name='yourInputName')) and change the value of this inputs=["yourInputName:0"]. For the output, unfortunately its always appending an Identity layer at the end of the model. I haven't yet found a solution to that.

Comment: I get the following error, when I try your approach of renaming the input: `TypeError: Expected argument names ['Input'] but got values for ['x']. Missing: ['Input']` Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: @random9, Sorry, kindly change also this line predictions = frozen_func(yourInputName=tf.constant([[3.]]))

Comment: Hi @random9, I also updated the answer so that it would be much easier.

Comment: @TF_Support, is there a way to use the code above to create a frozen graph for a custom model created using TF2?  In other words, is there a way to define 'model' in the code above as model = 'saved_model.pb' rather than model = tf.keras.Sequential() and then use the code above to create a frozen graph?  If so, how should the custom model be loaded into the code?  I tried model = 'file_location/saved_model.pb' but it is kicking out errors.  Thanks for any help you can provide!