# Do I get a frozen graph (or equivalent) from Tensorflow 2.X?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I need to have a frozen graph (`GrafDef` file) while using Tensorflow 2.X.
That is because I use a tool which expects a frozen graph, however, my training needed to be done on TF2.X and Keras.

---

I tried many different ways to save my TF2 model. The variant with which I was able to get the most useful formats is the following:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver(var_list=cnn.trainable_variables)
save_path = saver.save(sess, os.path.join(CHKPT_DIR, CHKPT_FILE))
tf.compat.v1.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, CHKPT_DIR, TRAIN_GRAPH, as_text=False)
```

That way I was able to get the following files:

- `float_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001`
- `float_model.ckpt.index`
- `checkpoint`
- `training_model.pb`

Of these files I need the `*.ckpt` and `training_model.pb` to freeze my model. However, when using the `freeze_graph.sh` (with TF1.X, different virtual environment), it throws the error

> ValueError: No variables to save

This is although I give it the variables as a list via `var_list=cnn.trainable_variables`. `cnn.trainable_variables` also is not empty and seems to have all the used variables of my model.

---

Thus, I tried using the following method, according to TF2.X standards (assuming `cnn` is my model):

```
cnn.save(CHKPT_PATH)
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(cnn)
save_path = checkpoint.save(CHKPT_PATH)
```

Here I get the following files:

- `float_model.ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001`
- `float_model.ckpt-1.index`
- `checkpoint`
- `floating_model.ckpt/keras_metadata.pb`
- `floating_model.ckpt/saved_model.pb`
- `floating_model.ckpt/assets`
- `floating_model.ckpt/variables`

---

But here is where I get confused. Is there some kind of frozen graph available already? Or is there some kind of equivalent in here? And if not, how to get it with TF2.X if possible? I found the sentence

> The `.save()` method is already saving a `*.pb` ready for inference.

in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974077/how-to-save-keras-model-as-frozen-graph/61004639#61004639). So the frozen graph is ready for inference, and thus one of these files must be equivalent to a frozen graph, right?

Comment: @AloneTogether Unfortunately not, but thank you!

Comment: And this? https://medium.com/@sebastingarcaacosta/how-to-export-a-tensorflow-2-x-keras-model-to-a-frozen-and-optimized-graph-39740846d9eb

Comment: @AloneTogether This may has helped! I will try and go on in my work. Maybe it was the solution. Thank you, anyways!