# Unable to load the frozen model (.pb) in GraphDef in tensorflow version 2.x

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, qualcomm, snpe

1. Created a simple dummy sequential model in `tf.keras` as shown below:

   ```
   model = tf.keras.Sequential()
   model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(100, 100)))
   model.add(layers.Conv1D(3, 2))
   model.add(layers.Flatten())
   model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predict_10'))
   ```
2. Trained the model and saved it using `tf.keras.models.saved_model`.
3. To get the `input` input and `output node names` used `saved_model_cli`.

   ```
   saved_model_cli show --dir "path/to/SavedModel" --all
   ```

   [image]
4. Froze the `saved model` with [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) utility.

   ```
   python freeze_graph.py --input_saved_model_dir=<path/to/SavedModel> --output_graph=<path/freeze.pb> --input_binary=True --output_node_names=StatefulPartitionedCall
   ```

   Model is frozen.

Now Here's the main issue:

5. To load the frozen graph I've used this guide [Migrate tf1.x to tf2.x](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#a_graphpb_or_graphpbtxt) (`wrap_frozen_graph`)
6. Used

   ```
   with tf.io.gfile.GFile("patf/to/freeze.pb", 'rb') as f:
      graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
      graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
   load_frozen = wrap_frozen_graph(graph_def, inputs='dense_3_input:0', outputs='predict_10:0')
   ```
7. Output error
   `ValueError: Input 1 of node StatefulPartitionedCall was passed float from dense_3/kernel:0 incompatible with expected resource.`

I'm getting same error when converting .pb to .dlc (Qualcomm).
Actually I want to run original model on Qualcomm's Hexagon DSP or GPU.

Comment: Use `model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')` library to load the saved model. For more information take a look at [tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format). Thanks!

Comment: @TFer My question was using frozen model and not using SavedModel which has separate files for weights and graph. `load_model` works for SavedModel. For edge devices it's good to have a single (pb) file.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56384808/14290244) answer your question . Thanks!

Comment: @TFer Thanks. This means Qualcomm SNPE doesn't support TF2.0 yet.